# Nexmo C# whatsapp integration

Tags: c#, curl, vonage

I need to configure my platform for deliver whatsapp messages. I have the curl code given in below taken from the Nexmo official site. But I couldn't able to send a message.

I did register on Nexmo account. They have only cUrl and Node codes are provided. So, I converted the curl code to c# online, and try to send message using the converted code. But I always getting the Bad request status code.

Pls help me how to configure it and provide answers for listed below question's too. And what should be the technical feasibility?

Questions:
1. What will be the "WHATSAPP_NUMBER" for the from address? 
2. How can I setup a new number as my from address?
3. Can I send messages to any numbers without any registration? If it is not, 
   where do I register all the sending(recipient) numbers?
4. What is the Message Template and its use? Do I need to purchase it?

```
  -u '0e63c0dgvhcfg1:QjHfhghvU07PHSJOnmdiH'\
  -H 'Content-Type: application/json' \
  -H 'Accept: application/json' \
  -d '{
    "from": { "type": "whatsapp", "number": "WHATSAPP_NUMBER" },
    "to": { "type": "whatsapp", "number": "918129267810" },
    "message": {
      "content": {
        "type": "text",
        "text": "Hello from Nexmo"
      }
    }
  }'
```

I am very new for whatsapp integration with Nexmo. Any help would be appreciated.

Comment: @alex, oh, thank you. I did, Can you help me about technical feasibility about this?

Comment: On Nexmo website I found that `"In order to get started with WhatsApp you will need to email sales@nexmo.com"` and that `"If successful, your account manager will provide you with a WhatsApp number."` If you don't have your WhatsApp number I think you should start with this. https://developer.nexmo.com/messages/concepts/whatsapp

Comment: I did it twice, but still didn't they contact me with any Whatsapp number.

Comment: I don't know what to say, it's weird that Nexmo sales would not get back to you. Try to contact Nexmo support then, (https://help.nexmo.com/hc/en-us) or look for another service provider.